# Replacing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I want to replace fragment B1 with fragment B2 after selecting listFragment A items.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Integer Position = position;
    WebViewerFragment fragment = (WebViewerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
    if (Position.equals(0)) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        WebViewerFragment newFragment = new WebViewerFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.detailFragment, newFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack("android");
        ft.commit();
    } else if (Position.equals(1)) {
        FragmentManager fms = getFragmentManager();
        WebViewerFragment_II newFragments = new WebViewerFragment_II();
        FragmentTransaction fts = fms.beginTransaction();
        fts.replace(R.id.detailFragment, newFragments);
        fts.addToBackStack("google");

        fts.commit();
    } 
}
```

It replaces just for once and after selecting item 1 (position 0) again application crashes.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the method `replace(int, Fragment)` of `FragmentTransaction`, the int must be the id of the container in which you want to put your new `Fragment` and in which were the previous one. Typically, it's a `FrameLayout`.
You can't replace a `Fragment` which has been set with XML.

Comment: Thanks. Now application doesn't crash but `addTobackStacK` doesn't work. When I change `ft.replace` to `ft.add` it works, too. Why?

Comment: I think it's a stack and when you click on back, you remove the fragment at the top. So, if you call replace, you will remove the fragment and nothing will remain. If you call add, you remove the last fragment, and the fragment below appear.